# WooCommerce: move ONLY regular price on single product page

Tags: woocommerce

I have a snippet by the following code:

```
remove_action( 'woocommerce_single_product_summary', 'woocommerce_template_single_price', 10 );
add_action( 'woocommerce_single_product_summary', 'woocommerce_template_single_price', 35 );
```

That works fine, to move the whole price block in the single product page (regular price and sale price, together)...

How can I move only the "regular" price?

Answer (score 2):

Just for clarification.
What is happening here **woocommerce_template_single_price** loads template **price.php** which outputs **$product->get_price_html()** which holds both regular and sale price.

Since you want to separate your prices we need to have two different actions for each price type.

```
remove_action( 'woocommerce_single_product_summary', 'woocommerce_template_single_price', 10 );
add_action( 'woocommerce_single_product_summary', 'custom_regular_price', 35 );
add_action( 'woocommerce_single_product_summary', 'custom_sale_price', 36 );

function custom_regular_price() {
    global $product;
    if($product->is_on_sale()):
        echo '<p class="regular-price"><del>'.get_woocommerce_currency_symbol().' '.$product->get_regular_price().'</del></p>';
    else:
        echo '<p class="regular-price">'.get_woocommerce_currency_symbol().' '.$product->get_regular_price().'</p>';
    endif;
}

function custom_sale_price() {
    global $product;
    //Move currency symbol depending on currency
    if($product->is_on_sale()):
        echo '<p class="sale-price">'.get_woocommerce_currency_symbol().' '.$product->get_sale_price().'</p>';
    endif;
}
```

Comment: Simply PERFECT... and well explained too. It works exactly as expected.- Thank you very much!   =)

Comment: Sorry... I just realized that -even when this was the solution for what I asked for- it's ignoring the currency format!
So, $ 110.725 it´s shown as $110725... is there a way to correct it?

Comment: I have added spaces for you **.'  '.**